# Android 'Complete action using' theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I would like to make an application that uses the same theme as the 'complete action using' app on Android 5. Does it even exist or do I have to write that on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out, how to achieve this. The theme is: Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar, then you need to add a fragment. Edit the theme so the activity is transparent:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

And finally set the background of the fragment to white.

```
android:background="@color/primary"
```